# What are some Objective-c debugging tips?

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I'm still haven't properly learned how to use the Xcode debugger, but I was wondering if anyone has some favourite debugging tips, things you can quickly insert into code to see the state of objects. Anything which would help me get more of a grasp on the internals of Objective-c.

Mostly I rely on `NSLog(@"%@", myObject)` to see what's happening with myObject, or sometimes `NSLog(@"%@", [myObject class])` to check that something is really the class it should be. I know that I can do both by using the debugger, but I want to try using code for the moment, before I take the leap into using a full debugger.

Do you have any similar tricks?

Comment: Don't put everything on  one line.  If you access an index inside a dictionary inside an instance of a custom class, make each level of access a separate temporary, vs "daisy chaining" everything together.  Easier to maintain and easier to debug, since you can see all the intermediate values with the debugger.

Comment: In the console, when stopped at a breakpoint, type "help".  It will show you the available debugger commands.  Become familiar, especially, with "po", since it will reliably display stuff the variable display window won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asserts. Lots and lots of asserts.  When you assume something must be some way, assert that it is true.

Build & Analyze is the new Build.  Use the Clang Static Analyzer in Snow Leopard.

There is no magic;  everything on your system and in your code happens for a reason, including crashes & misbehavior.

Embrace the debugger;  it is really powerful and quite easy to start using.

Greg Parker's weblog is a wonderful source for a "behind the curtains" view of how some things work:  http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/

Answer (score 3):

I also use a lot of NSAsserts all around my code.
Here are 2 useful articles by Chris Hanson about NSAssert:

- [Disable assertions and logging in
  your release build](http://chanson.livejournal.com/169786.html)
- [Distinguish between checks and assertions](http://chanson.livejournal.com/170068.html)

Another debugging technique I use often:
As Xcode does not display array contents in the debugger view, you can use the (gdb) console or the expression window to list array contents.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484707/viewing-a-dynamically-allocated-array-with-the-xcode-debugger) is a related SO post.